# How to reuse react-native code in a next.js (with react-native-web support) project?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webpack, next.js, code-reuse

Reusing code between react-native and react-native-web is fairly well documented.  Reusing code between next.js and react-native-web works perfectly thanks to "create-next-app --example with-react-native-web project_name".

I am trying to reuse code between react-native and next.js, which is a little different.  Next.js hides all of its webpack / babel manipulations and I suspect that's where the issues arise.

I created a RN project with "react-native init rn1" and a separate project with "create-next-app --example with-react-native-web nj1"

I carefully copied the nj1 folders to the rn1 project, including hidden folder ".next", then carefully merged the package.json files to make sure the "scripts" don't collide and the dependencies are correct.

The command "react-native run-ios" correctly builds and starts up the simulator.  Running "react-native run-android" works flawlessly also.

The problems arise when I try to run the Next.js project with "npm run dev" in which case I get:

Failed to compile.

```
./node_modules/next/dist/client/next-dev.js 34:6
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (34:6)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|
|
> import('./noop');
| var _window = window,
|     assetPrefix = _window.__NEXT_DATA__.assetPrefix;
```

Has anyone faced this issue before?

The package.json resulting from merging both project folders looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "testweb7",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "rn-start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest",
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^3.1.2",
    "next": "^8.0.3",
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-native": "0.58.6",
    "react-art": "^16.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "react-native-web": "^0.9.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "24.3.1",
    "jest": "24.3.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.53.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Thank you for reading!

Comment: BTW, "npm run build" builds the next.js project correctly, and by correctly I mean there are no errors shown on the terminal.  The problem shows when I run the project with "npm run dev"

Comment: UPDATE: I made some progress.  It seems that commenting out "import('./noop');" on line 34 of next.js' distribution file ./node_modules/next/dist/client/client-dev.js fixes the problem. Go figure...